# Evaluate $\int_C \frac{1}{z} dz$ where $C$ is the path joning $-i$ and $i$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$\int \limits_C \frac{1}{z}dz$$ where $C$ is the path joning $-i$ and $i$.

Consider figure:

[image]

If take the integral along the above mentioned path, then $F(z) = Log(z)$ is an antiderivative for $f$ on any domain $D$ that contains the path as in the sketch, hence $$\int \limits_C \frac{1}{z} dz= Log(i) - Log(-i) = \pi i$$

This part I get, however, the following part I do not understand.

Consider now the following figure:

[image]

Then (according to my notes) $F(z) = \log_0(z)$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on any domain $D$ to the left of the Imaginary axis containing the curve.

Why do they take the logarithm along the branch $0$?

The answer it gives if then $$\int \limits_C \frac{1}{z} dz= \log_0(i) - \log_0(-i) = -\pi i$$

The answer makes sense intuitively, because we are taking it in the opposite direction as in the first one, hence the negation. I just do not understand why they use $\log_0(z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this integral to make sense (be independent of path) you need to always indicate a branch. Such branch prohibits some paths altogether. In the first case, you are taking to branch as usual $\Im (z) = 0, \Re (z)\leq 0$, the anti-derivative in this sense is the Logarithm. In the second case though you need to change the branch since this path cuts through the previous branch. Say you out the branch as $\Im (z) = 0, \Re (z)\geq 0$, now you denote the anti-derivative as $\log_0$ which is clearly different from $\log$.